# I'm periodically getting a Windows Security login dialogue - How can I tell what's causing it to appear?

Tags: windows-7, authentication

I've just switched on a PC for the first time in several months, and I'm periodically getting the following Windows Security dialogue box prompting me for a Username / password:

[image: dialog box]

Now, the server name in question relates to my previous job, and I did have email, VPN etc for that job set up on this machine.  I thought I'd uninstalled everything related to that, but obviously not, and it seems that something is still trying to connect & is then triggering the dialogue.

How can I tell what the errant program is that's trying to establish this connection?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a networked drive.. check My Computer for any disconnected drives.

Is it at random times or every X hours? You could look in Schedule Tasks for corporate antivirus updates, etc.

Comment: Yeah, a networked drive was a possibility but no, there aren't any listed if I select "Computer -> Disconnect Network Drive".  Still, I think it might be triggered by using Windows Explorer, so something along these lines is a possibility.

Comment: You could try searching your registry for the server name/ip.

Comment: There was never corporate antivirus or scheduled tasks set up on this machine, so it's not that.

Comment: Searching now...

Comment: No joy with searching the registry :\

Comment: You might check in the Group Policy settings, though I'm not familiar with those under Win7. You could also check your Events listings to see if there are any entries for those prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Please get [System Explorer](http://systemexplorer.net/) installed and try to check the process tree which is invoking this. When the dialogue box appears, there must be a corresponding entry in currently running processes. Click "go to process". You'll see the process tree from which its originated. 
If this doesn't solve, check the process related modules in System Explorer.